# How to make a server for more than 4 people?

Tags: alien-swarm

I know there are Alien Swarm dedicated servers for 5 or 6 players.

How do I create a game for more than 4 people?

It may be by listen or dedicated server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments on badp's answer, the standard campaign maps do not support it, so there's no telling where you'll end up without modifying it.

However, as in any source game, you can do this by adding `-maxplayers 6` to the SRCDS command-line. 6 is a limit hard-coded into the game.

You can also try entering `maxplayers 6` in the <kbd>`</kbd>Developer Console for a listen server, but I'm not sure whether that works.

If 6 doesn't work, try entering a higher value like 10, it should clamp to 6.

Comment: `-maxplayers 6` didn't work. I also "Cannot change maxplayers while the server is running"

Comment: @BlaXpirit Then why did you accept this?

Comment: @BlueRaja - Because it's the only answer that applies to the actual game? :-)

Comment: This answer contains the smallest amount of "this is impossible" words

Comment: @BlaXpirit - It is however practically impossible, without modding the game.

Comment: Well, guys, this is possible! I'm currently running a dedicated server with 5 players without any mods!

Comment: Then, how do you did it? (post it as an answer)

Answer (score 6):

With a [server-side mod](http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=134628), you can have up to 10 player slots.  However, only five will be able to play - this is [hard-coded limit](http://forums.alliedmods.net/showpost.php?p=1264139&postcount=2) in the game.

There is [a mod](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1410742) which allows for up to 8 players, but it requires both the server and all the clients to use custom .dll's *(you cannot join normal servers using these dlls, so make sure to backup the default ones!)*.  Of course, since it relies on replacing dlls, future alien swarm updates may break it.

Comment: This would make my answer correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Without modding anything -- the default campaign only allows for 4 players. Custom campaigns, however, have the option to allow up to 5 people in a single mission.

Comment: False. Please remove the answer

Comment: @Blax, feel free to downvote if you believe the answer is incorrect. It is as accurate as I know.

Comment: OK. As you wish

Comment: It is true, you can't play with more than 4 people on the standard campaign since there aren't enough spawnpoints.

Comment: It is **false**! I'm playing with 4 other teammates *right now*!

Comment: @Blax, what campaign? I did say 5 player servers are possible.

Comment: Jacob's Rest [default] campaign

Comment: badp you can play with more than 4 people in the regular game in the regular campaign, I've done so myself. Wasn't the host though, don't know how it was done.

Comment: @Oak ask the host, get +25 :)

Comment: @Blax -- if you want to be helpful on this site, your **third** and **forth** comments on this answer should have been your **first**

Comment: @BlaXpirit - It is, due to technical limitations, impossible to do with the unmodified standard campaign. The map will have to be modified to allow it.

Comment: @Oak, if you have to mod the server you aren't really playing the default campaign, you're playing the modded default campaing. The game may still believe it's the official campaign and award XP, but then it's kinda akin to cheating. (You have 5 people on a mission that has difficulty adjusted for 4 players.)

Comment: @badp maybe - all I know is that as far as I could see, I was connecting to a regular server.

Comment: I don't care about "XP", because I have maximal level and all the achievements. I just asked how I can make a server for 6 people.